# Display Matrix to get a unique Pattern

Tags: java

I want to construct a square matrix (2D) of size n (which will be input by the user)
Now I want to construct a diagonal pattern.
For example (3X3 Matrix):

```
                       2        3
                           1
                       4        5
```

The `value` variable will be initialized to 1 and stored at the center of the square matrix. Then `value` will be incremented and stored at upper left corner as shown above, and so on.

It is a simple program to be displayed on console.
User input can taken from command line.
I am trying to generalize a condition in a for loop that will work for square matrix of size 5,7,9... (odd numbers).
For a matrix of size 5 it will be

```
                       6               7 
                           2        3
                               1
                           4        5
                       8               9
```

(the empty spaces can be zero)

My code:

```
import java.util.*;    

public class MatrixAdv  
{
    public static void main(String args[])    
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter size of element...");

        int n=sc.nextInt();    //stores size of Matrix
        int value=0;    //To be incremented everytime to get the Pattern

        int [][] matrix = new int[n][n];

        int k=0;
        for(int i=0;i<some Condition;i++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<some Condition;j++)
            {                   
                k=n-2-j; 
                matrix[k][k]=++value;
            }     
        } 
    }

    //Display the value in matrix form
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {  
            Print(matrix[i][j]+"\t");
        }
        Print("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question? is the code not working? it have a bad performance? do you want to know if there are better ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically 2 options for solving this:

1. Go through the whole matrix, row by row and column by column, and check whether a certain value has to be set at the current position
2. Go through all the positions where a certain value has to be set.

Both of them have nothing to do with the condition of a `for`-loop. However, here an example for the second approach:

```
public class MatrixAdv
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        //Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //System.out.println("Please enter size of element...");
        //int n = sc.nextInt(); // stores size of Matrix
        int n = 9;

        int value = 0;// To be incremented everytime to get the Pattern
        int[][] matrix = new int[n][n];

        matrix[n/2][n/2] = 1;
        int maxValue = ((n / 2) * 4) + 1; 
        int r = n / 2 - 1;
        int c = n / 2 - 1;
        int d = 2;
        for (value=2; value<=maxValue; value++)
        {
            matrix[r][c] = value;
            int step = ((value-2)%4);
            switch (step)
            {
                case 0: c+=d; break;
                case 1: r+=d; c-=d; break;
                case 2: c+=d; break;
                case 3: d+=2; r-=d-1; c-=d-1; break;
            }
        }

        // Display the value in matrix form
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                if (matrix[i][j] == 0)
                {
                    System.out.printf("%3s", "_");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.printf("%3d", matrix[i][j]);
                }
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

its very easy to print 99% matrix patterns if you know the magic of matrix...and you can do it without using any memory.

here is the code......

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    if(n == 1)
        cout<<1;
    else
    {
        int sv=2*n-4,a,b;
        a=sv;b=sv+1;
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
            {
                if(i == j && i+j == n+1)
                {
                    cout<<" 1 ";
                    sv=4;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    if(i == j)
                        cout<<" "<<a<<" ";
                    else if((i+j) == n+1)
                       cout<<" "<<b<<" ";
                    else
                       cout<<"   ";
                 }
            }
            if(i < n/2+1)
            {
                sv=sv-4;
                a=sv;b=sv+1;
            }
            else if(i > n/2+1)
            {
               sv=sv+4;
               b=sv;a=sv+1;
            }
            else
            {
               sv=4;
               b=sv;a=sv+1;
            }
            cout<<"\n";
        }
   }
}
```